# Changing word inflections

Tags: nlp

This might be an unusual question. I have a situation where I am creating paraphrases with a rule based system. One transformation that I'd like to implement would one that gets rid of light verbs, like so:

a) Steven made an unwilling concession to us.

b) Steven unwillingly conceded to us.

To go from (a) to (b) requires some inflectional changes such as:

unwilling -> unwillingly

concession -> conceded

Is there something out there that can take care of such inflectional changes reliably for a given word? Seems like there should be, but I don't recall seeing anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share what I found here.

I have not tried any of this yet, but this looks very good, the [Automatically Generated Inflection Database (AGID)](http://wordlist.aspell.net/agid-readme/).

There is also the [SPECIALIST Lexicon](https://lsg3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lexicon/current/web/index.html).

And for those using python, there are various modules you can use, such as [LemmInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect).